# Is it possible to boot a Craig CLP281 netbook from a USB stick?

Tags: boot, bios, netbook

I have a [Craig CLP281 netbook](http://www.craigelectronics.com/site/pdetails.php?id=314) with Android 2.2 on it.  I'd like to try running a minimal version of Ubuntu on it, but can't find out how to get it to boot from a USB stick.  I can't even get into the BIOS settings.  Does the CLP281 have a BIOS even?

Comment: Looking at the specs i'm guessing its arm based, and a x86 based version of ubuntu certainly would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the product page...

http://www.craigelectronics.com/site/pdetails.php?id=314

... and noticing that the OS is loaded as Firmware, as well as reading the installation instructions... I'd have to say that No.  There is not any way to get it to boot to a USB stick to install Ubuntu.  Even if you could... the device doesn't appear to boot to the 4g of flash memory the unit uses for storage.  The unit boots to the OS embedded on a ROM chip and uses the flash memory *just* for storage.  Think of it like an Android touchpad with a keyboard... or a big phone.  The instructions for loading the OS are very specific, and require using files designed for the process.  Click the Installation link at the bottom of the product page and read them, to see what I mean.

THAT said... some hard core geeks have modified the version of Android.  One such geek post here with links to the modified ROM and Source files.  http://www.worcesterdwi.com/thread-67136-1-1.html

Comment: Thanks Bon.  See this link too, which talks about using a debian image and VNC in some way I don't understand: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1392593

Comment: Your link looks like a more advanced post from the same guy who made the post in my link... oddly just a day before tho.  Same essential information, but more advanced.  He hadn't tested the USB with the "special" cable in the link I had found.  However, it appears that the limited version of Debian is used to either load or modify the ROM... see his references to ensuring that the Android Market is included in the ROMs.